# Creation of multiple test cases in JIRA using java

Tags: java, jira, jira-zephyr

How to create multiple test cases in Jira using Zephyr(in Java)

Answer (score 0):

On the Atlassian marketplace you can find the [ZAPI add-on](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.thed.zephyr.zapi/server/overview) which makes REST API calls available for Zephyr. The add-on is not free though.

From your java app (or groovy scripts or whatever), you can use your favorite REST client library to call the ZAPI resources to create tests, but you'll have to check the docs [here](https://zephyrdocs.atlassian.net/wiki/display/DEVELOPER/ZAPI).